# Search with location returns internal server error

Tags: android, parse-platform

I've problem with building search request on android.

```
   ArrayList<ParseQuery<Entity>> queriesByCriteria = new ArrayList<>();
   queriesByCriteria.add(ParseQuery.getQuery(Entity.class).whereContains("userName", criteria));
   queriesByCriteria.add(ParseQuery.getQuery(Entity.class).whereContains("locationName", criteria));
   queriesByCriteria.add(ParseQuery.getQuery(Entity.class).whereContains("descriptionBefore", criteria));
   queriesByCriteria.add(ParseQuery.getQuery(Entity.class).whereContains("descriptionAfter", criteria));

   ParseQuery<Entity> combinedQuery = ParseQuery.or(queriesByCriteria)
                            .orderByDescending("createdAt")
                            .whereEqualTo("done", true);

   float mapRadius;
   int mapUnits = preferences.getMapUnits();
   if (mapUnits == MapUnitType.MAP_UNIT_KILOMETER) {
       mapRadius = (preferences.getMapRadius());
   } else {
       mapRadius = 1.6f * (preferences.getMapRadius());
   }
   entities = combinedQuery
                            .whereWithinKilometers("location", new ParseGeoPoint(latLng.getLatitude(), latLng.getLongitude()), mapRadius)
                            .find();
```

So find() throws exception "com.parse.ParseException: internal error".

Version of Parse SDK is 1.7.1

Is it bug of parse.com or I do something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, internal errors in SDK's refer to errors which are internal and not meant to be exposed to user's of the SDK. In this case, there is an edge case not handled internally by the find() method. My recommendation would be to go to the [Parse suppport page](https://parse.com/help) and report this as a bug.